# The database is not updated

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Previously, my database was updated successfully, but after I needed to upload documents to storage, my database stopped updating. Fields remain unchanged.

First, I delete the old file, then upload the new one and replace the file name in the database. And update all the data.

Files updated successfully but data not updated

```js
export const UpdateProject = data => async (
  dispatch,
  getState,
  { getFirestore, getFirebase }
) => {
  const firestore = getFirestore();
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  try {

    await firestore
      .collection("Mission")
      .where("idMission", "==", data.idMission)
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          let project = doc.data();
       
          firebase
            .storage()
            .refFromURL(
              `gs://nospace-92826.appspot.com/Missions/${project.idMission}/${project.NameDoc}`
            )
            .delete();
        });
      });

 
    await firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`Missions/${data.idMission}/` + data.document.name)
      .put(data.document);
   
   data.NameDoc = data.document.name;
   
    delete data.document;
   
    await firestore
      .collection("Mission")
      .doc(data.idMission)
      .update({ ...data });
  } catch (err) {}
};
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest not mixing up code using async/await with then/catch.  It'll be easier to reason about your code if you use just async/await.  In particular, think carefully about the promise being returned from `delete()` that your code is ignoring.  Adding debug logging might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: You are calling `delete data.document;` for? If you want to update the `document` field then you should set your new property there. If you want to remove the field from database then set it to `null`.

Comment: @JoshuaChan I call delete because firestore does not support file data type. This array field I do not need in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updatable fields cannot be undefined, I thought that they would be ignored when sending

And i just delete them

```js
 delete FormData.LinkBoss
    delete FormData.LinkWorker
    delete FormData.TextDone
    delete FormData.MissionDoneTitle
```